# "431 Request Header Fields Too Large"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

so I get  this error every time I re-render the site

" GET http://localhost:3000/api/ShopItems 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)"

I can see that my fetch doesn't go as planed and invokes the error above ⬆️

The chrome developer tool points me to the "ShopItemsActions" fill

```js
import { FETCH_SHOPITEMS } from "../types"


export const fetchShopItems = ()  => async (dispatch) => {
    const res = await fetch("/api/ShopItems");
    const data = res.json();
    console.log(data);
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_SHOPITEMS,
        payload: data
    });
}
```

The chrome developer tool mark the third line "const res = await fetch("/api/ShopItems")"

Question: how can i fix  this error?

Edit:

the server  side code

```js
const express  = require("express");
const bodyParser  = require("body-parser");
const mongoose  = require("mongoose");
const shortid = require('shortid');



const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/bread_project_db", {
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
});

const ShopItem = mongoose.model(
    "ShopItems",
    new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {  type: String, default: shortid.generate },
    name: String,
    image: String, 
    price: Number,
    info: String,
    flourType: [String],
}))

app.get("/api/ShopItems", async (req, res)=>{

    const ShopItems = await ShopItem.find({});
    res.send(ShopItems);

});

app.post("/api/ShopItems", async (req, res)=>{

    const newShopItem = new  ShopItem(req.body);
    const savedShopItem = await newShopItem.save();
    res.send(savedShopItem);
});

app.delete("/api/ShopItems/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const deletedShopItem = await ShopItem.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
    res.send(deletedShopItem);
  });

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen( port, () => console.log(`server at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

I am using postman and I dont have cURL installed for some reason.
the postman just show this:

**431 Request Header Fields Too Large**

The server is unwilling to process the request because either an individual header field, or all the header fields collectively, are too large. Proposed in an Internet-Draft.

Comment: How does this api looks on the server side ?

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any (added) request headers at all - the problem is possibly somewhere else - what request headers do you see in the browser console - does your API make a request of some other server, adding request headers?

Comment: Can you show the curl that you are sending to the server?

Comment: To copy request to curl format you need to open the network tab in Chrome, right-click "Copy > Copy as cURL"

Comment: @KrystianSztadhaus - how is `curl` relevant?

Comment: When we will be able to see cURL then we will be able to confirm that you are not sending "too much headers"

Comment: The code you shared doesn't contain any header related stuff. Do you have any interceptor handles headers? Or Maybe an issue with the response header. Please share the complete request and response.

Comment: That's why I asked for cURL, maybe something is adding these headers ( middleware, chrome plugins, etc )